# Voltage controlled resistor

Tags: ltspice

I want to built a varying resistive load in LTspice. I tried using a resistor with Value defined as V=V(Vresistance) where Vresistance was the netname of the voltage source (pulsed). But this had some error shown below.

[image]

I want the value of resistor to follow the voltage waveform. Is there anyway to achieve this in LTspice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change the resistance value of your resistor to one with curly braces.
The component's value is usually something like this

```
R=20k
```

You put:

```
V=V(Vresistance)
```

You need to use this for the components value:

```
R={V(Vresistance)}
```

Here are other ways to make a variable component:

```
R={V(Vresistance)}
R={I(Vresistance)}
C={V(Vresistance)}
C={I(Vresistance)}
R={V(Vresistance)*I(Vresistance)}}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get `Can't find definition of model "V"`

Comment: Post the line of the netlist for the resistor

Comment: Minimum example:

`B1 Vin 0 V=1 \n

R1 N001 Vin {V(Vin)}   \n

.tran 1m   \n

.backanno  \n

.end`    (Can't post multiple lines here so using `\n` as newline symbol)

Answer (score 5):

You can write the expression directly:

R={120k+5k*sin(2*pi*2k*time)}