# LTspice resistor value stepping

Tags: ltspice, simulation, dummy-load

I have built a DC power supply circuit in LTspice with a current limiter and voltage foldback.

The circuit works, but I want to take a load resistor and set it to 1 Ω initially, then step it down incrementally in 0.1 Ω increments until it is 0.1 Ω, for example, one step every 0.1 seconds.

Could someone help me write the step parameter or point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 1):

The step parameter doesn't work this way. When you use `.step`, the SPICE core will perform multiple *individual* simulations, each one with a different set of parameters according to the stepping scheme. The `.step` directive can't step parameters *during* a running transient simulation.

To step at different time points within a single transient simulation, use a PWL voltage source and a [voltage-controlled resistor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/335514).